# Display a back-tick within back-ticks

Tags: github, markdown

Within a markdown code block (using back-ticks) I need to display a literal back-tick.

As an example, a line like below where every `B` is replaced with a back-tick:

```
B foo B bar B
```

I've tried escaping the back-tick like this:

```
B foo \B bar B
```

but it's still not rendering properly.

My use-case is for a GitHub `README.md` but the same issue also happens when I try this in StackOverflow.

How can I show a back-tick within a back-tick block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
``A single backtick: ` more text``
```

renders as

`` A single backtick: ` more text ``

Inline code can be enclosed by any number of backticks.

See the [original documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code) ("literal backticks"), and also this [Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown).

Comment: It's worth noting that on Stack Exchange, [comments are handled differently when it comes to backticks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213182/197875). In comments, `\`` must be escaped (i.e. `\`A single backtick: \\` more text\`` in order to render `A single backtick: \` more text`)

Comment: @Cornstalks Good point, I'll add that. Edit: looks like it works with enclosing in multiple backticks, also in comments...?